# dynamic page break in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, page-break

I have a report that displays summary data for three years. Each page displays data for one year. The the report is set to have thee pages. However, for some year that the summary data is negative and there is  no need to show. Is there a way to skip this page in the report? There is way to hide controls based on rules, but I couldn't find any way to hide entire page output.

Comment: you dont want to show negative data in the report? if thats what you want, filter it from the source!

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you can simply choose to filter the dataset so that rows/records with negative values do not appear.